# Can I get back an array in Protractor by.Repeater rather than a string?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, automation, protractor

I have an ng-repeat directive that I am looking to use the Protractor repeater to get back an array:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in landingPage.products" class="landing-buttons">
    <a ui-sref="personalInfo">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{{product}}</button></a>
</div>
```

I just want the {{product}} string to come back in an array, but I just get what looks like a JSON string instead. Any suggestions here?

Comment: can you post one example of the JSON like result?

Comment: Yeah - this is what I am getting back: [ 'Accident & Health', 'Disability', 'Life' ]

Comment: Can you show what code are you executing currently? Thanks.

Comment: I am executing this in my spec: it('should have correct product text', function () {
    expect(landingPage.allButtons.getText()).toEqual([ 'Accident & Health', 'Disability', 'Life' ]);
  }); - but I would rather break it down to get the text of "Accident & Health" as index[0] of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually on the `allButtons.getText().

This function is being applied over the angular element and the result is the concatenation of everything that matches the criteria: **button**. (Which are N based on the ng-repeat, and therefore gives you the array).

Please check if you can, base on the `allButtons` attribute, find the one the interest you the most. e.g:

```
expect(landingPage.allButtons.first().getText()).toEqual('Accident & Health');
```

*Edit: Fixing the assertion to use first() instead elementAt(0) as mentioned by @alecxe*

Comment: If we translate it to the "protractor" language:  `expect(landingPage.allButtons.first().getText()).toEqual('Accident & Health');`. But, aside from that - the answer makes perfect sense and on the correct track.

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I needed - wanted to make sure I was using Protractorese. Thanks @Custodio and @Alexce!

Comment: Is there a tutorial on ".first?" - can I use .second and .third as well?

Answer (score 1):

While .first() helped me get the first element, for any subsequent ones I used .get(index).

```
it('should have buttons', function () {
expect(landingPage.allButtons.first().getText()).toEqual('Accident & Health');
expect(landingPage.allButtons.get(1).getText()).toEqual('Disability');
expect(landingPage.allButtons.get(2).getText()).toEqual('Life');
});
```

This works now. Thanks all for your help.